# Laravel5, PHPUnit and Date Mutators: can't use mutator in data provider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I've just noticed that we can't use date mutators in a test data provider. Example

```
class FooTest extends TestCase {

    /**
     * @dataProvider baz
     */
    public function testBar($baz) {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    public function baz() {
        $model = new Foo(['someDate' => \Carbon\Carbon::now());
        return [
            [$model]
        ];
    }
}
```

Given your model like this

```
class Foo extends Model {

    public function getDates() {
        return ['someDate'];
    }

}
```

That test will produce the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function connection() on null in /var/www/agents/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 3224
```

That's because in eloquent Model we have

```
protected function getDateFormat()
{
    return $this->dateFormat ?: $this->getConnection()->getQueryGrammar()->getDateFormat();
}
```

which is trying to access the connection that is not established in the test data provider.

So, how should we provide that `testBar()` method an input model?

Comment: Any reason you are not using factories to create the model instances with fake data using faker methods?

Comment: I need to control what data is in the model in order to provide significant input data. How is that relevant?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run this in your dataProvider. This because it gets the dataProvider data before it have run CreateApplication code. This can also generate `The data provider specified for x is invalid.` PHPStorm will only say `No tests executed!` if a single test is run.

```
public function baz() {
    $this->refreshApplication(); 
    $model = new Foo(['someDate' => \Carbon\Carbon::now());
    return [
        [$model]
    ];
}
```